# cat a filename in docker command in cloudbuild

Tags: docker, unix, gsutil, google-cloud-storage, cloudbuild.yaml

I need to pass the output of file to docker command as an argument. I know that `$TAG_NAME` is already avaliable, i have my value in a file which is dynamic. Is there a way we can access the file and pass it in docker run step.

```
cat /workspace/tagvalue.txt
```

My steps:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${_IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG}', '-f' ,'${_DOCKER_FILE}', '.' ]
```

Somehow need to output the cat to TAG variable

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the value from file like this

echo $(<tag.txt) | tr -d '\n'

Here echo will print the value with additional new line. We need to run tr command on the output to remove trailing newline.

Comment: Can use **echo -n** instead of piping the output to delete the new line.